# How to generate one cart with multiple items using BigCommerce cart API in nextjs

Tags: next.js, bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce API with Nextjs and I am trying to understand how cart API works from BC ( https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/20c2c55c1763f-create-a-cart ).

When I implement it as it is there, whenever I click on Add to cart button (same/different item ) it generates a new cart with that item.

I don't know how to keep adding items to the same cart (with the same cart-id, etc). There is no API for updating the current cart (i.e. send PUT req with new items on api/cart/cart-id).

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Add Cart Line Items Storefront API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/6b15c26ac7d24-add-cart-line-items)? I think this might be what you are looking for to add products to an existing cart.

A